# PHP converting mysql to excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Working on PHP converting to excel, but having problems in the excel file where it doesn't add each row in its own cell. Here is how it looks: https://www.dropbox.com/s/64lz7lqy8z7x72j/export.csv
It writes it on the first cell and it looks like it has written to all of the cell.

[image]

And here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('chart', $conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM chartgoogle', $conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));

header('Content-Type: text/csv'); // tell the browser to treat file as CSV
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export.csv'); // tell browser to download a file in user's system with name export.csv

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // Get the column names
if ($row) {
    outputcsv(array_keys($row)); // It wil pass column names to outputcsv function
}

while ($row) {
    outputcsv($row);    // loop is used to fetch all the rows from table and pass them to outputcsv func
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}

function outputcsv($fields) {
    $separator = '';
    foreach ($fields as $field) {

        echo $separator . $field;
        $separator = ',';        // Separate values with a comma
    }
    echo "\r\n";     //Give a carriage return and new line space after each record
}

?>
```

Comment: Use a tab separator rather than a comma (though MS Excel is locale-specific about which it uses), or add a `sep=<char>` as the first line of your csv file to identify the separator that you're using; or save as a real Excel BIFF or OfficeOpenXML format file

Comment: And why not use PHP's built-in fputcsv() function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function outputcsv($fields) {
    $csv = '';
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $csv .= '"' . $field . '",';
    }
    $csv .= "\r\n";     //Give a carriage return and new line space after each record
    echo $csv;
}
```

Take a look at the double quotes placed before and after the field. CSV files usually use double quotes as closures. They call it text qualifier.

Comment: That didn't work. It still save rows from the first cell. So editing isn't being fun with that setup.

Comment: Weird,when I tested it without `header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );`. Excel could open it correctly. But when I tested with the header, it puts the row into one cell.

Comment: Yeah, its really weird why it puts each row just in one cell.